# Dilemma in using "so" or "too"

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, sentence-structure, adverbs, spoken-english

I always believe that the usage of ***so*** and ***too*** is different from each other:

> He is ***so*** busy until he is able to forget his problems. (=+ve sense)

and another one

> He is ***too*** busy until he does not have time to eat.(-ve sense)

---

Consider the following sentence:

> i)This place is ***so*** hot.
>
> ii)No wonder, the shirt's ***so*** big.

How about the sentences above?

Is it ***grammatically permitted to use them interchangeably***?

Answer (score 1):

The error you have made is that "so" has *two different uses*. One is an adverb which has a similar application as "too", for example:

> That is so kind of you.
>   That is too kind of you.

However, the meaning is not identical and they are not strictly interchangeable. "So" means "to a great extent" whereas "too" means "to an *excessive* degree" (although some colloquial expressions break this rule).

In your examples, it seems like you intend to use "so" as a *conjunction*, although you are not using it correctly:

> He is so busy until he is able to forget his problems.

It seems that you are trying to say he forgot his problems *because* he was so busy, in which case it should be phrased as:

> He was *so* busy *that* he forgot his problems.

Comment: You could possibly equate the adverb usage of *so* to *very*. *That is **very** kind of you*. *This place is **very** hot*